# How to set variables for setter methods via java reflection

Tags: java

I'm having an entity class defined as EmployeeBase.java which has 200 setter methods and 200 private variables declared for the same.

I'm having an Employee.java which extends the base class EmployeeBase.java which has few fields as well.

Now i want to create Random values for all the fields in Employee.java and return Employee object.

I'm not sure how to set all the values of setter which exist in Employee and in base class.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Most modern IDE’s support getter and setter generation. Also you probably shouldn’t have 200 variables in one class, you can usually group them into other classes.

Comment: I already have getter and setters but i am looking for the object with random values being assigned to it. I already generated getters and setters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some libraries as the goal of reducing the time and effort of create Junit tests, such as [Podam](http://mtedone.github.io/podam/) and [Easytest](https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest) for example. For simplicity, I like to use Podam in my tests.

1. Add Podam dependency to your pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
       <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
       <version>7.0.5.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Write yours beans:

   2.1. **People.java**

   ```
   public abstract class Peopple {

       private String name;
       private String mail;
       private List<String> phones;

       public String getName() {return name;}
       public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
       public String getMail() {return mail;}
       public void setMail(String mail) {this.mail = mail;}
       public List<String> getPhones() {return phones;}
       public void setPhones(List<String> phones) {this.phones = phones;}
   ```

   }

   2.2. **Course.java**

   ```
   public class Course {

       private String code;
       private String name;

       public String getCode() {return code;}
       public void setCode(String code) {this.code = code;}
       public String getName() {return name;}
       public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
     }
   }
   ```

   2.3. **Student.java**

   ```
   public class Student extends Peopple {

       private Course course;

       public Course getCourse() {return course;}
       public void setCourse(Course course) {this.course = course;}

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Fill your beans using Podam:

   ```
   public class PodamDataGenerator {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           PodamFactory podamFactory = new PodamFactoryImpl();
           //Limit number of elements to collections fields
           podamFactory.getStrategy().setDefaultNumberOfCollectionElements(2);
           Student student = podamFactory.manufacturePojo(Student.class);
           System.out.println("Podam Pojo\n-----------\n " + student);
       }
   }
   ```
4. The output

   ```
   Podam Pojo
   -----------
   Student[course=Course[code=Dr0zgS5ZKw,name=ZrGJ8xAcJQ],
           name=nB6zy558W5,mail=DuW6YyLgo3,phones=[Wlc7axk_A7, nQxDmUlukY]]
   ```

Hope this helps!